# Calculate "bounding box" for multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array, bounding-box

So we have a 5x5 2d-array like so:

```
gridmodel:
[
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

This represents how a blocky object looks like and how it is drawn on a grid, so we could have something like this for example:

```
gridmodel:
[
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

Which would represent a simple T-block from tetris. If the shape does not start from the top left corner, the shape is just shifted in runtime, so that it works correctly.

Anyway that is kind of irrelevant. What I need is a way to calculate a bounding box for any shape in this 5x5 grid. The shape can have holes or the shape can consist of just a single 1 in the array, basically the 5x5 can be any combination of 1's and 0's.

To calculate a bounding box I figured I just need to find which 1 is the most top- and leftmost and which 1 is the most right- and bottommost.

I made this, which is supposed to find the top-left 1:

```
var bb = 
{ 
    x1: null, 
    y1: null,
    x2: null,
    y2: null
}

var toppest = null;
var leftest = null;

for(var y = 0; y < gridmodel.length; y++)
{
    for(var x = 0; x < gridmodel[y].length; x++)
    {
        if(gridmodel[y][x] === 1)
        {
            if(toppest === null)
            {
                toppest = { x: x, y: y };
            }

            if(leftest === null)
            {
                leftest = { x: x, y: y };
            }
            else
            {
                if(x < leftest.x)
                {
                    leftest = { x: x, y: y };
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this looks already way over complicated and it barely solving half of the problem.

Comment: @Teemu Ahh, I forgot indexOf and lastIndexOf. Thanks for  the reminder to you too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much what you thought of but you only need 1 number in boundaries. You can check for default values (max val, -1) to see if anything was found.

```
var topmost = Number.MAX_VALUE;
var leftmost = Number.MAX_VALUE;
var bottommost = -1;
var rightmost = -1;

for(var y = 0; y < gridmodel.length; y++)
{
  var l = gridmodel[y].indexOf(1);
  var r = gridmodel[y].lastIndexOf(1);

  if (l >= 0 && l < leftmost) leftmost = l;
  if (r >= 0 && r > rightmost) rightmost = r;

  // only check if some 1 found
  if (l >= 0 && y < topmost) topmost = y;
  if (l >= 0 && y > bottommost) bottommost = y;
}

bb = {x1: leftmost, y1: topmost, x2: rightmost, y2: bottommost};
```

Comment: Great! This is working perfectly with what I currently have. I completely forgot indexOf and lastIndexOf, so a great reminder there too.